# How to retrieve all country name with counting to NSArray from NSDictionary?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

Here is my dictionary result.

```
"continent_code" = EU;
"country_code" = gb;
"country_id" = 169;
"country_name" = "United Kingdom";


NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData      
encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *LoginResult = (NSDictionary*)[responseString JSONValue];
```

I want to retrieve only country name to NSArray from dictionary.

Comment: can you post your entire response dictionary.

Comment: Dictionary response is all the country name in world..

Comment: So the dictionary contains an array of countryNames and details?

Comment: [yourarry addObject:[LoginResult objectForKey:@"country_name"]];

Comment: [yourarry addObject:[LoginResult objectForKey:@"country_name"]] but i wrote in forloop like?????

Answer (score 0):

Try This ::

```
NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

NSLog(@" Value :: %@", [[jsonArray JSONRepresentation] JSONValue]);

for (NSDictionary *item in jsonArray) {
   NSLog(@" Item :::::> %@", [item objectForKey:@"country_name"]);
}
```

Hope, It'll help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSMutableArray *wholeJsonArray = [LoginResult objectForKey:@"RootName"];
 NSMutableArray *loginArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

 for(int i = 0 ; i<[loginArray count];i++)
    {
        NSString *countryName=[[loginArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"country_name"];
       [loginArray addObject:countryName];
    }
```

Good luck !!

Answer (score 0):

The Correct Method to fill **countryArray** :

```
NSError* error;
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:yourResponseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSArray* getMAS_CR = [(NSDictionary*)json objectForKey:@"yourKeyRootResult"];
NSMutableArray *countryArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (NSDictionary *rr in getMAS_CR)
{
    NSString *cName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[rr objectForKey:@"country_name"]];
    [countryArray addObject:cName];
}
NSLog(@"countryArray :: %@",countryArray);
```

GoodLuck.